# Does it make sense to use a varchar column as foreignkey reference?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many, varchar

Given two tables `books` and `authors` where each of them already have a unique key which is of `varchar` type which identifys them throughout my ecosystem. **Does it make sense to use those keys as Foreignkeys in the Many-To-Many-Table or should I invent a primary key in the tables `authors` and `books` which is of type `int` to avoid overhead?** The length of those keys already existing is not more then 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer surrogate keys. It protects you from unkown changes in the future, because it is decoupled from application data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to use int key as primary key. Firstly - you will avoid overhead, secondly - you will gain some performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe you could explain a little why you think so? Is it because of performance issues?

Comment: Performance in particular. Comparing varchars takes longer than ints. Secondly - adding auto-increment key is much faster than going through database and checking if the varchar key already exists. This can be really bad when your database grows big enough.

Answer (score 0):

int will be the better way.  you may have a large effort to redo existing data however - which may influence you to not make the change...

i would suggest that making this change earlier rather than later will be easier for you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new Primary Key is a good idea, 
as a primary key also enforces a not null constraint.

Answer (score 0):

While I also think int keys are better, I don't think you should make any changes to your primary keys as it already works. Your varchar keys may make sense if it is, for exemple, ISBN codes for the books. *If it's not broken, don't fix it*.